# Rvest nodes undetected with html_nodes

Tags: css, r, rvest, rselenium

I can't quite understand why I can't use selectors on some websites with Rvest.

Example:

```
url <- read_html("http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics")

headlines <- url %>%
html_nodes(".headline") %>%
html_text()
```

Another example:

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)
rD
remDr <- rD$client

url <- "http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics"
remDr$navigate(url)

remDr$getTitle()
remDr$getCurrentUrl()

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = 'headline')

webElem$getElementAttribute("class")

remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
```

It should be simple enough. When I look at the structure, the titles are under  then  class headline. Above that there is class card-content, card-content-top but no combinations of css selectors nor xpath seems to work.

Comment: I see no class headline or a class card-content (?)

Comment: When I look at the page in the developer console, it's there. Even when using SelectorGadget, that is the css selector that is identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors may not work in rvest due to the selectr package having some issues (at least on Debian), see this for more info:
https://github.com/sjp/selectr/issues/7

Using SelectorGadget and Chrome Developer tools, I used the following xpath to find and identify the 'headlines' from the webpage. More info on how to find the correct xpath can be found here:
https://medium.com/@peterjgensler/functions-with-r-and-rvest-a-laymens-guide-acda42325a77

```
library('rvest') 
library('magrittr') 
url <- read_html("http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics")


headlines <- url %>%   
html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "pinnableHeadline", " " ))]') %>% 
html_text()

headlines[1]
"On Trudeau's 2nd trip to China, time may be ripe to advance free 
trade"
headlines[2]
"Liberals want to be global leader on open government, but face complaints at home"
```